# sql database constraint

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

Whether unique key constraint could contain more that one NULL value in it's column?

Comment: That depends on the DBMS product you are using

Comment: I am talking about in general theory concept!!!

Comment: @prabhasthakur . . . There is no "general theory" about SQL.  There are only databases that only interpret and implement something resembling a standard.

Answer (score 0):

In a word - yes.

A unique constraint means you can't have more than one row with the same value. But `null`s aren't values - they are the lack thereof, "empty" cells, if you will.

Comment: That depends on the DBMS. Oracle for example does not allow multiple NULL values in a single column index (but does for multi-column indexes). SQL Server never allows multiple NULL values in a unique index: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=581b194813fb881cfa42883d76c68e75 or https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2be5fbaccc0e85bc9905670228ad1367

Comment: I read _unique (key) constraint_, which allows several null values (ANSI SQL). However, a _unique index_ usually not allows multiple nulls (not covered by the ANSI SQL specification.)

Comment: @jarlh: there is no difference between a unique constraint and a unique index regarding nulls (a primary key constraint would be different though as that usually implies a NOT NULL constraint)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the ANSI SQL specification about unique constraints (ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E), 4.23.3.2 Unique constraints): "_is satisfied if and only if there do not exist two rows R1 and R2 of T such that R1 and R2 have the same non-null values in the unique columns._" (The ANSI SQL specification does not include unique indexes, but it seems like most products do not allow multiple null values.)

Comment: @jarlh: define "most" ;) Postgres, Oracle (multi-column unique constraints), MySQL HSQLDB, h2 and SQLite allow multiple null values. SQL Server, DB2, Firebird and Oracle with a single-column unique constraint will not.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Sorry, perhaps I jumped to conclusions when talking about _unique indexes_, I haven't checked them all - and they are not covered by the SQL standard. (I should have said "I have a feeling that" instead of "it seems like".)

Comment: Thanks guys for ur valuable comments